# What are the good compile time defect analyzing IDE plugins?

Tags: java, .net, visual-studio, eclipse

There are many code quality tools but we missing compile time defects most of the time. If we have track of our mistakes we can easily reduce coding time by reducing compile time defects.is there any compile time defect analyzing tools for programming?

Comment: You should choose one IDE and one programming language for this question.

Comment: Checkout [FindBugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/) for eclipse. Also see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tools_for_static_code_analysis

Comment: Are you asking for a tool that logs and reports on compiler errors? Because a "compile time defect analyzing tool" sure sounds like the compiler itself otherwise.

Comment: @OedipusPrime: He's asking about a real time analyzer.

Comment: @OedipusPrime yes, you are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) is a great tool, it's actually the best one there is for C#.
[Visual Assist](http://www.wholetomato.com/) is also not half bad and helps with more languages.